# MySql LEFT JOIN Takes a Long Time - Indexes have been added

Tags: mysql, left-join

I use the following query

```
SELECT a.job_number as f31jn, b.job_number as f32jn
FROM 
f31 a LEFT JOIN f32 b 
ON (a.job_number = b.job_number AND a.date_audit = b.date_audit)
WHERE date_format(a.date_audit, '%b %Y') = 'Dec 2012'
GROUP BY a.job_number, a.ref_id, b.job_number, b.ref_id
```

The above query takes around **160** seconds to complete.

I have added indexes to the following columns:

```
f31 - job_number, date_audit (separate indexes)
f32 - job_number, date_audit (separate indexes)
```

`EXPLAIN` of the above query results in
[image: EXPLAIN]

### **EDIT**

Changed the query to

```
SELECT a.job_number as f31jn, b.job_number as f32jn
FROM 
f31 a LEFT JOIN f32 b 
ON (a.job_number = b.job_number AND a.date_audit = b.date_audit)
WHERE a.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' AND a.date_audit < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY a.job_number, a.ref_id, b.job_number, b.ref_id
```

and still the execution times doesn't come down. It stays in the same proximate range of 150 to 160 seconds.

The `EXPLAIN` now comes up as
[image: EXPLAIN 2]

For table `a`, it is still searching in 90% of the records (Total records are around 68k).

Comment: First of all, MySQL cannot use an index to resolve your `WHERE` clause; try instead `WHERE a.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' AND a.date_audit < '2013-01-01'` and then post back with the results.

Comment: If you use functions like "date_format(a.date_audit, '%b %Y')", mysql will skip indexes

Comment: eggyal has given you the first part of the solution, the second is to amend the index on f31 to date_audit, job_number

Comment: @symcbean: Maybe; maybe not.  Indexes which include the grouped columns may be more productive.  Depends on cardinality.  Awaiting to see result of my suggested modification.

Comment: @eggyal Let me see how that works

Comment: Doesn't help much..maybe a difference of 5-6 seconds.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM f31 a WHERE a.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' AND a.date_audit < '2013-01-01'`?  If that number is over 40k then you probably cannot improve this query.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL cannot use an index to help with `date_format(a.date_audit, '%b %Y') = 'Dec 2012'`.

Do you have separate indexes on job_number and date_audit or one combined index.  If it is a combined index then again MySQL cannot use it for any form of query on date_audit alone. Either create an index on date_audit by itself or a combined index with date_audit first and job_number second.

Then convert the `WHERE` clause to compare date_audit to actual date values.

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but worth a try:

First, time this:

```
SELECT * from f31 a 
WHERE a.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' 
  AND a.date_audit < '2013-01-01'
```

It should be quite fast. If not, you need to verify your indexes and the types (DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP) of the `date_audit` columns.

Then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.job_number as f31jn, b.job_number as f32jn
FROM 
  (SELECT * from f31 aa 
   WHERE aa.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' 
     AND aa.date_audit < '2013-01-01') as a    
LEFT JOIN f32 b 
ON (a.job_number = b.job_number AND a.date_audit = b.date_audit)
```

If this doesn't nail it then please set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the schema and at least a few pieces of test data.

Comment: The indexes are seperate, i.e. one for job_number and one for date_audit

Comment: OK, here's some more stuff for you to try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The first query hardly took 1-2 seconds. It returned 14k rows. The second query didn't help. It took the same amount of time as my previous query did. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I can't provide a SQL Fiddle with pre-filled data as we are bound by NDA. Thanks for the help though. Giving you +1

Comment: One interesting thing I found was that when I used the first query, 14k rows were returned and it was quick retrieval. However, when I added `EXPLAIN` for that same query, it shows that it does a full table scan inspite of `date_audit` being listed under `possible keys`. I wonder why there is a full table scan.

Comment: You don't need to fill in thousands of rows on the SQL fiddle, just a few dozen, and there's no disclosure with just job numbers and dates. MySQL will do a full table scan if it needs to pull in data that is not in the index and it needs to pull in a significant fraction of the table; it's just faster than scanning the index and then scanning the table.  Outer Joins are notoriously hard for RDMSes;  can you get what you need by rewriting the query as a UNION of 2 JOINS or 1 JOIN and 1 single table query?

Answer (score 1):

Consider refactoring this part first:

```
date_format(a.date_audit, '%b %Y') = 'Dec 2012'
```

Into:

```
a.date_audit >= '2012-12-01' && a.date_audit < '2013-01-01'
```

And another thing, try adding combined indexes instead like this:

```
f31 - (date_audit, job_number)
f32 - (date_audit, job_number)
```

MySQL will only use a single index per table, so having them combined should nominate them for both the join and the query on `date_audit`.

Comment: Already tried that as seen in the `EDIT` section of the question